# How to stop scrolling of Recyclerview inside the Scrollview?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

In my Project, I put a recyclerview inside the Scroll view. Recyclerview is working fine and scrolling well.I don't want the scrolling of recyclerview.When scroll the screen whole layout should scroll.But now only the recyclerview is scrolling.How to stop that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` attribute in your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I just spent a solid hour trying to figure this out, everyone says this is the answer in API21+ but they fail to mention the layout needs to be wrapped inside a ScrollView

Comment: this part is included in the question "I put a recyclerview inside the Scroll view"

Comment: I understand that and perhaps my comment was poorly worded as that's how I figured it out... Just noting that seemingly everywhere else this was asked the ScrollView part was omitted.